# Resize webview on keyboard display in Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, android-studio

I'm developing an online store with webview. However, every time a text area was selected, the android keyboard started and rescaled the application disproportionately. I followed some tips given in the forum, entered the code

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"
```

and managed to solve the problem, but now, the keyboard starts and I can not see what is being typed. The image below, shows how the webview is behaving.

How can I make the app to scroll to the top of the keyboard?

[image]